# python requests upload large file with additional data

Tags: python, file-upload, python-requests, large-file-upload

I've been looking around for ways to upload large file with additional data, but there doesn't seem to be any solution. To upload file, I've been using this code and it's been working fine with small file:

```
with open("my_file.csv", "rb") as f:
    files = {"documents": ("my_file.csv", f, "application/octet-stream")}
    data = {"composite": "NONE"}
    headers = {"Prefer": "respond-async"}
    resp = session.post("my/url", headers=headers, data=data, files=files)
```

The problem is that the code loads the whole file up before sending, and I would run into MemoryError when uploading large files. I've looked around, and the way to stream data is to set

```
resp = session.post("my/url", headers=headers, data=f)
```

but I need to add {"composite": "NONE"} to the data. If not, the server wouldn't recognize the file.

Comment: Looking at the code in models.py, PreparedRequest class, prepare_body method, there's no way to use requests to stream upload large file with additional data.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [requests-toolbelt](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.org) to do this:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart import encoder

session = requests.Session()
with open('my_file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    form = encoder.MultipartEncoder({
        "documents": ("my_file.csv", f, "application/octet-stream"),
        "composite": "NONE",
    })
    headers = {"Prefer": "respond-async", "Content-Type": form.content_type}
    resp = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=form)
session.close()
```

This will cause requests to stream the `multipart/form-data` upload for you.

Comment: Thanks so much! I remember coming across requests-toolbelt before, but didn't think of putting Content-Type into the header!

Comment: Yeah the documentation for the toolbelt pretty explicitly says you need that. :)