# What is the maximum size of the payload we can send as POST request in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, payload

I am sending a POST call to the server. the size of the payload is 114757153(114Mb)

Post call request:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

I understood that the data variable was not able to read the complete 114mb, so it is throwing unsuccessful msg.

What is the best way to send a 114mb payload as a request to the server?

Comment: "it is throwing unsuccessful msg" - please post the _full_ traceback

Comment: I think this is an xy problem. It's entirely possible the server can't handle the payload.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python requests upload large file with additional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779879/python-requests-upload-large-file-with-additional-data)