# How can I write Python code that uploads a file larger than RAM?

Tags: python

I had a vps with 1 GB ram and i wanted send a big file (2GB ) by curl and python.

python gave `MemoryLimit` error but `curl` send file without problem and use very low memory.

How curl did it?

How i can send a very big file in a Http post request with use low memory?

Comment: Applications use virtual memory, they're not limited by the amount of RAM.

Comment: @Barmar So you're saying curl actually did load all 2 GB into (virtual) memory at once and then sent them?

Comment: @Carcigenicate If he's using a library to upload the file, the file reading is internal to the library.

Comment: Why would you read the whole file into memory at once, instead of reading (and sending) a block at a time?

Comment: This question would be helped by a [mre] -- an example of your upload code, so answers can be written to use roughly the same tools (are you using `urllib`? `urllib2`? `requests`? something else?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have loaded all file data into memory and then tried to send it. This obviously results in MemoryLimit error.

You could try to use `mmap` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html). A sample code would be as follows:

```
import requests
import mmap

with open("hello.txt", "r+b") as f:
    # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    r = requests.post(URL, data=mm)
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)
    mm.close()
```

Comment: Is `mmap` actually necessary? I think `post` already handles file-like objects in a streaming fashion if necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure! See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779879/python-requests-upload-large-file-with-additional-data

Comment: @chepner Unfortunately `post` don't handle this case